# Parabola Vertices - Vertex Formula: Finding the vertex of y=6x^2+3x-9

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, conic-sections

[image: Image of Problem]

Greetings. I found the X in the vertices applying the -b/2a and getting -1/4, however, when I try to solve for y I get -75/8 or -9 3/8 (I even placed the equation in [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=6%28-.25%29%5E2%2B3%28-1%2F4%29-9) and got the same answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I get this as well.

Comment: Did you try to enter the solution as $-{75\over8}$?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Yes, I found out that I had to input the answering a fraction. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{equation} \begin{split}
y &= 6 x^2 + 3 x - 9 \\
&= 6 (x^2 + \frac{1}{2} x) - 9 \\
&= 6 ( (x + \frac{1}{4} )^2 - \frac{1}{16} ) - 9 \\
& = 6 (x + \frac{1}{4})^2 - \frac{3}{8} - 9 \\
&= 6 (x + \frac{1}{4})^2 - \frac{75}{8} \\
\end{split}\end{equation}$

Which means the vertex is at $(-\dfrac{1}{4}, - \dfrac{75}{8} ) $

So your answer is correct.